A race to the bottom
Nate has a biased coin that comes up heads $\frac{1}{2} + \delta$ proportion of the time, where $0 < \delta \leq \frac{1}{2}$. He is competing against a large number $N$ people who each have fair coins that turn up heads exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ of the time.
Assume that on each round played, each player, Nate included, flips their coin. If heads comes up, they are given one ($1$) point, otherwise nothing happens. Assume all flips are independent of each other.
Countably many rounds are played. We shall call the player who has the most points on the current round the current “leader” of the race.
The law of large numbers says that almost surely, there exists some random $X > 0$ such that Nate leads the race for all rounds after and including the $X$’th round. We take our $X$ to be the smallest such round number.
Indeed, on round $k$ he is competing against the maximum of $N$ independent $\text{Bin}(k, \frac{1}{2})$ random variables, which has a smaller mean asymptotically as $k \to \infty$, whence by the LLN, Nate is fated to win.
Question: Is it true that there exists some absolute constant $C > 0$ such that
$$\mathbb E[X] \leq C \delta^{-2} \log N?$$

The random variable X should have order p^(-2) log N with high probability: this is what’s needed for the drift to beat the fluctuations. I think you should be able to prove moment bounds of the correct order using fairly naive union bounds over the other players.

@tmh Nice, can you think of anything stronger than union bounds?

Sure, you can probably describe the full limit distribution in terms of all the usual extreme value theory stuff for the other players .

From the point of view of stochastic processes, this is a rather hard one to analyse since $X$ depends inevitably on the full filtration $\mathcal F_\infty$, despite seemingly making itself known with high probability much earlier.

Any reason for the downvote? Is something not clear in the problem set up?

@NateRiver : I did not downvote your post. However, $EX$ must depend, not only on $p$ but also on $N$. Also, you apparently want to deal with the minimal "random $X > 0$ such that Nate leads the race for all rounds after and including the $X$’th round."

@IosifPinelis Yes indeed, i should make those points clear in the post.

@IosifPinelis Do you see a way of doing this exactly in the case $N = 1$? I have some Borel-Cantelli type bounds in that case but no exact answer…

@tmh I managed to get, with the most naive union bounds possible, $\mathbb E[X] \lesssim \delta^{-2} N$. I could likely improve this to the suggested $\mathbb E[X] \lesssim \delta^{-2} \log N$ with a slightly more clever way of porting the bound. More or less I should create a “tournament structure” over the other players first…

Did you try using an upper-tail estimate for the random walk like Azuma-Hoeffding? The log N should come from the Gaussian tail.

I'll try that out, sounds like a good idea indeed... @tmh

@tmh With such an estimate, i get only $C \delta^{-4} \log N$.

Curious, where does the fourth power come from?

Maybe i’ll write out the computation in full to make sure! @tmh

@tmh Yes it was just a miscomputation on my part it seems.

$\newcommand\de\delta$Let $U_i$ be the indicator of heads in the $i$th round for the biased coin. For each $j\in[N]:=\{1,\dots,N\}$, let $U^j_i$ be the indicator of heads in the $i$th round for the $j$th unbiased coin. Let $Y^j_i:=U^j_i-U_i$, $Z^j_k:=\sum_{i\in[k]}Y^j_i$, $Z_k:=\max_{j\in[N]}Z^j_k$. Then, for $n=0,1,\dots$,
$$\{X>n\}=\bigcup_{k\ge n}\{Z_k\ge0\};$$
of course, here we are assuming the minimal version of a random $X>0$ such that Nate leads the race for all rounds after and including the $X$'th round.
Also, $EY^j_i=-\de$ and $|Y^j_i|\le1$. So, by Hoeffding's inequality,
$$P(Z^1_k\ge0)\le e^{-k\de^2/2}.$$
So, for $n=0,1,\dots$,
$$P(X>n)\le\sum_{k\ge n}P(Z_k\ge0)\le N\sum_{k\ge n}P(Z^1_k\ge0)
\le N\sum_{k\ge n}e^{-k\de^2/2}\asymp\frac N{\de^2}\,e^{-n\de^2/2}.$$
Also, trivially, $P(X>n)\le1$. So, for $N\ge2$,
$$EX=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X>n)
\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\min\Big[1,\frac N{\de^2}\,e^{-n\de^2/2}\Big]\asymp
\frac1{\de^2}\,\ln\frac N{\de^2}.$$

ah, so i did miss something - the $\delta^{-2}$ in $\ln \frac{N}{\delta^{-2}}$ I don’t think can be removed.

Here is an estimate for $\mathbb E[X]$ that I believe to not yet be of sharp order. The idea will be to handle the case $N = 1$ first.
We let first $Z_n = Y_1 + \dots + Y_n \sim Bin(n, p)$ denote a generic binomial random variable.
We know $Z_n / n \to p$ a.s. Hence given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some minimal $U(p, \varepsilon)$ such that we have $X_n / n \geq (1 - \varepsilon)p$ for all $n \geq U(p, \varepsilon)$. By Hoeffding’s inequality,
$$\mathbb E(U(p, \varepsilon)) \leq C \varepsilon^{-2} p^{-2}.$$
Meanwhile, if we set $L(p, \varepsilon)$ to be that minimal value such that $X_n / n \leq (1 + \varepsilon)p$ for all $n \geq L(p, \varepsilon)$, then by symmetry and the above bound we have
$$\mathbb E(L(p, \varepsilon)) \leq C \varepsilon^{-2} (1-p)^{-2}.$$
Finally, we note that in the case $N = 1$ where there is only one opponent,
$$X \leq \max(U(\frac{1}{2} + \delta,  \frac{\delta}{2}), L(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\delta}{2})),$$
so that, by a simple sum bound for the maximum, we obtain
$$\mathbb E[X]  \leq C\delta^{-2}.$$
In the generic $N$ case, we can naively port this bound over to get
$$\mathbb E[X] \leq C \delta^{-2} N.$$
but this is far from the desired $C \delta^{-2} \log N$.
